# Building a VECM to predict values / cointegration residuals of another set using a Johansen test (urca package)

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, autoregressive-models

I have a dataset with several variables that I'm trying to cointegrate in order to build a system that can detect when the variables oscillate in an unsual manner.

To do so I tested for stationarity and differenced them I(1). After that I used the Johansen test (ca.jo) to estimate the number of relationships and applied the cajorls function to estimate an OLS regression.

Now, all this was done using a set of observations that have a normal behaviour. I would like to apply these estimated coefficients to a new set of observations and see if their behaviour is consistent or not.

From what I've read we can compare the Cointegration residuals using a control chart to know if any observation is out of control or not. How can I estimate said residuals of this new set of observations (The output from cajorls already gives me the residuals from the normal behaviour) using the coefficients estimated?

[output from ca.jo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL0aK.png)

[output from cajorls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEeKj.png)